# how to use microsoft 365 online form with my account

Tags: office365, administrator, microsoft365

Your account is not enabled for Microsoft Forms
Please contact your administrator for access, or switch to an authorised account.
Technical details
Session id: e49f401f-ce14-43b2-96da-7e06d279fddf, Correlation id: b63f0457-f88f-4677-890b-429d06b9d9f2

I login into my microsoft365 account on their website  and tried to use the form app. I  was expecting a form to show up but it didn't. it showed "your account is not enabled for Microsoft form, Please contact your administrator for access, or switch to an authorized account.